# Using Distributed cache and FileReader on single node Cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Is it necessary to have multiple node clusters or single node cluster is enough for using Distributed Cache.
Can FileReader open the file stored in HDFS directly by giving path of file.

Answer (score 0):

it is actually not a must. the main intention behind using distributed cache is to make the resources available to all the mappers or reducers running on all the nodes throughout the cluster, which doesn't make much sense on a single machine. on a single node hadoop cluster you could just have a global variable in your mapreduce code and that would do the trick.

Comment: Is it possible to check whether the file is present in Distributed Cache or not after this statement
         DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(otherArgs[2]), conf);